# Capture xsl:message output in java

Tags: java, xslt

I'm trying to capture xsl:message in java when calling my transform.  Below is a snippet of my code.

```
        final ArrayList<TransformerException> errorList = new ArrayList<TransformerException>();
        ErrorListener errorListener = new ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void warning(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            errorList.add(e);
          }

          @Override
          public void error(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            errorList.add(e);
          }

          @Override
          public void fatalError(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            errorList.add(e);
            throw e;
          }
      };
      ...
      try
      {
        transformer.setErrorListener(errorListener);
        newDoc = transform(transformer, oldDoc);
      }
      catch (TransformerException e) {
        log.error("Problem transforming normalized document into PUBS-XML", e);
        throw e;
      }
```

Unfortunately this is not working.

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which xslt processor are you using?

Comment: believe I'm using Xalan with javax.xml.transform.*.  My stylesheet are version 2.

Comment: Correction.  processor is Saxon.  Answer below is the solution for capturing xsl:message output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Saxon, then you may need to [set the message emitter using setMessageEmitter()](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/Controller.html#setMessageEmitter%28net.sf.saxon.event.Receiver%29).

https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/trans/XsltController.html#setMessageEmitter-net.sf.saxon.event.Receiver-

> `public void setMessageEmitter(Receiver receiver)`
>
> Set the Receiver to be used for xsl:message output.
>
> Recent versions of the JAXP interface specify that by default the
> output of `xsl:message` is sent to the
> registered ErrorListener. **Saxon does
> not implement this convention.**
> Instead, the output is sent to a
> default message emitter, which is a
> slightly customised implementation of
> the standard Saxon Emitter interface.
>
> This interface can be used to change the way in which Saxon outputs
> `xsl:message` output.

[Michael Kay has explained why Saxon doesn't output `xsl:message` according to the JAXP interface, and has suggested two options for obtaining the output](http://www.devcomments.com/cannot-get-ErrorListener-to-work-at90719.htm):

> `ErrorListener` was something that was
> introduced to JAXP at a rather late
> stage (one of many regrettable
> occasions where the spec was changed
> unilaterally to match the Xalan
> implementation), and **I decided not to
> implement this change as a default
> behaviour, because it would have been
> disruptive to existing applications**.
>
> In Saxon, `xsl:message` output is
> directed to a Receiver, which you can
> nominate to the Transformer:
>
> `((net.sf.saxon.Controller)transformer).setMessageEmitter(....)`
>
> If you want to follow the JAXP model
> of sending the output to the
> ErrorListener, you can nominate a
> Receiver that does this:
>
> `((net.sf.saxon.Controller)transformer).setMessageEmitter(new net.sf.saxon.event.MessageWarner())`

Comment: net.sf.saxon.event.MessageWarner is the right class for older versions (9.3 and earlier?) of Saxon, and Saxon-CE (which is based on the 9.3 codebase). It is net.sf.saxon.serialize.MessageWarner in newer versions of Saxon. Note that this sends messages to the warning() method of ErrorListener, unless terminate="yes" in which case it sends them to the error() method.

Comment: In case anyone is interested: I made a wrapper for Saxon's TransformerFactory here: https://github.com/nverwer/cocooncomponents/blob/master/src/org/apache/cocoon/components/xslt/SaxonTransformerFactoryImpl.java

Comment: “Recent versions of the JAXP interface specify that by default the output of xsl:message is sent to the registered ErrorListener.” ⇒ Where is this specified? I have checked JSR 206 - JAXP 1.6 and the Javadoc for [Transformer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) and [ErrorListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/ErrorListener.html) and couldn’t find any reference to the treatment of `xsl:message`.