# How to capture the output of XSLT's xsl:message in Mule

Tags: xslt, mule, saxon

I've an XSLT to transform XML in Mule 3.3.0 application. I've to stop processing and throw an error if data is not in conformance to requirements. I am using beloe code to achieve that.

```
<xsl:message terminate="yes">ERROR: Invalid Requirement Type Code: <xsl:value-of select="$vendorTransCode" />
</xsl:message>
```

In my `Mule` flow, am using `<catch-exception-strategy>` to catch the `TransformerException`, but how do I get the message outputted by`<xsl:message>`? How can I modify the behavior of `Emitter`? (guessing that's what I need to do)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4699749/14419

Comment: I did see this link before posting my question but am specifically looking to achieve this in Mule. Mule provides its own XSLT transformer and internally it uses saxon processor. With Mule I don't have to write any donkey code for Transformer so not sure where will Emitter code fits in